# Using Sumproduct to count nth digit in column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula that works in Excel, I am trying to count the occurrences of J as the 2nd digit

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(J2:J2000,2,1)="J"))
```

The problem is I can't seem to get this to work in VBA...

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = temps.Range("J2:J2000")
n = Evaluate(WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(--(Mid(rng.Address, 2, 1) = "J")))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Evaluate, evaluates a string not a worksheetfunction.

Comment: `n = temps.Evaluate("SumProduct(--(Mid(" & rng.Address & ", 2, 1) = ""J"")")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I got it by slightly modifying your code, I forgot about the string bit! n = temps.Evaluate("SumProduct(--(Mid(" & rng.Address & ", 2, 1) = " & Chr(34) & "J" & Chr(34) & "))")

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit a solution into the question itself. If you've found a solution you'd like to share, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot I needed to pass a string to evaluate. The following worked:

n = temps.Evaluate("SumProduct(--(Mid(" & rng.Address & ", 2, 1) = " & Chr(34) & "J" & Chr(34) & "))")